# Javascript spam script code filter

Tags: javascript, spam, spam-prevention, chatroom

I am hosting a chatting site, and I put a java script on there to stop spamming. If someone posts the same sentence or word, it will not post a second one. I've recently noticed someone using a different spam technique by saying the same word, but putting numbers at the end of it increasing. For example like this: Spam,Spam1,Spam2,Spam3, and so on. So if any of you guys know what the code is or how he's scripting this I'd appreciate the help because I'm not sure what the script is.

Comment: As your filtering is in JavaScript, it's easy for your clients to remove, or alter the mechanisms you put in place. You ***need*** to do all of this on your server, where it cannot be edited by your users.

Comment: I understand i can do other methods but just knowing the script would make it much easier to block it

Comment: What's your chat server? I can show you how bad of an idea this is if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option would be to run a more general comparison between submitted posts/words. This very well could be a custom script, and trying to specifically target individual techniques will allow them to continually make minor tweaks to get around your countermeasures. This could be done using the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of two strings. Just adding a number would result in a post with a very short Levenshtein distance between it and the original, so you can just ignore submissions that are too similar to previous ones. There are numerous server-side libraries you can use for this that should be able to get this done, but I can't really recommend anything without knowing how you're running the website.

Comment: So using this method will eliminate this spam

Comment: It can be used to cut back on spam that is reliant on repeatedly submitting very similar posts, yes.

Comment: It's a general technique, if you set the threshold too low it will be easy to evade, and if you set it too high, it will squelch similar posts needlessly (false positives). Experiment, and maybe implement additional checks (if you only compare to earlier messages from the same client, you can set the threshold much higher than if you filter all clients against the same database, for example). This is an arms race, so whatever you come up with, somebody will be able to subvert.  Whether they perceive it as worth pursuing depends a lot on external factors like what sort of site you are running.